# Spelling words backwards

Tags: java

I have a problem when I compare the new word with the original word.  I'm suppose to type in words like "banana" and take the first letter to the end and it should spell it backwards to equal "banana". The two words are equal. And if I type in "dog" it becomes "dgo". But in my code if i type in "banana" it still shows it not equal. Idk what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project9 
public static void main(String [] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String word, afc, newWord;
String s="";

do
    {
    word=keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
    int i =word.length()-1;
    char firstLetter=word.charAt(0);
    afc=word.substring(1);
    newWord= afc+firstLetter;

    for( ; i>=0; )
    {
        s += newWord.charAt(i--);
    } 
    System.out.println(word + "," + s);

        if (s.equals(word))
            System.out.println("Words are equal.");
        else
            System.out.println("Words are not equal.");
    }
while (!(word.equals("quit")));

}
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: Pay close attention to language conventions. Java uses indentations to make the code more readable. See the official style guide: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#262
But first and foremost, programming should be fun. So bookmark that and get back to it when you have the time.

Comment: your code is ... unique. Try to think like "how do I have to write my code to be able to understand it instantly when I look at it in 5 years."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code prints the word in reverse with

```
for( ; i>=0; )
  System.out.print(newWord.charAt(i--));
```

but then you're comparing the non-reversed version with

```
newWord.equals(word)
```

I think you want something like:

```
String s = "";
for( ; i>=0; )
  s += newWord.charAt(i--);
System.out.println(s);

if (s.equals(word))
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing **banana** and **ananab**
apart from it, you are doing so many operations for a small task.

 string manipulation is not a good practice because each time you change the string, it creates a new String object. I have written a  code for your requirement, hope it helps

 **char array is better than String when you need to manipulate it many times**

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, newWord;
    do  
    {
        word=keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        int i =word.length()-1;
        char[] ca=new char[i+1];
        ca[0]=word.charAt(0);
        for( int j=1; i>0;j++ )
        {
            ca[j]=word.charAt(i--);
        }
        newWord= new String(ca);

        System.out.println(word+","+newWord);

        if (newWord.equals(word))
            System.out.println("Words are equal.");
        else
            System.out.println("Words are not equal.");
    }
    while (!(word.equals("quit")));
}
```